# buttons not displaying in expo react navigation header

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo, react-native-navigation

I was following [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons) tutorial to learn react navigation in expo. in this header when i give button it is not getting displayed in the header. code below

```js
export default function App() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={Homecomponent}
            options={{
              headerTitle: ()=> <Icon name="home" />,
              headerRight: () => (
                <Button
                  onPress={() => alert("This is a button!")}
                  title="Info"
                  color="#00cc00"
                />
              )
            }}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

The `headerRight` button is not getting displayed.

TIA

Comment: Well it worked when i removed 'title' from button and added a 'Text' inside button. it worked.

`headerRight: () => (
              <Button
                onPress={() => alert("This is a button!")}
                color="#00cc00"
              >
             <Text>Info</Text>
              </Button>
            )`

Answer (score 0):

```
 import { HeaderBackButton } from 'react-navigation-stack';
//import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';// add if you have this

   export default function App() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={Homecomponent}
            options={{
              headerTitle: ()=> <Icon name="home" />,
              headerRight: () => (
                <HeaderBackButton 
                  onPress={() => alert("This is a button!")}
                  //title="Info"
                  color="#00cc00"
                />
// Here you can add your icon to show info sample code for icon is 
// <Icon name="info" size={25}/>
              )
            }}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

try this code may be helpful for you